# Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. - Ya se agregó un elemento con la misma clave

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, form-submit

Tengo un formulario que tiene un modelo definido.
Un boton submit con el Add correspondiente en el controller.
Sucede lo siguiente:
Si le quito el parametro al create del controller, es decir el objeto igual al de la vista, no me tira el error del titulo, pero claramente no recibo todos los parametros del formulario.
Ahora si agrego un objeto de esa clase como parametro, me tira el error del titulo.

Si el formulario lo dejo vacio, solo con el boton guardar, y en el controller le dejo el objeto como parametro. llega bien, pero nuevamente sin datos por cuestiones logicas.
El error esta relacionado al modelo que estoy usando en la vista.

Cual puede llegar a ser el error?

```
    @model CRM.Business.Entities.ModeloUno
@using GridMvc.Html;
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Generic.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","ModeloUno",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="heading" class="page-header">
                <h1><i class="icon20 i-cogs"></i>Configuración</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="icon"><i class="icon20 i-table"></i></div>
                            <h4>Nueva ModeloUno</h4>
                            <a href="#" class="minimize"></a>


                        </div>
                        <!-- End .panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="pager">
                                <li class="previous">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ModeloUno")">← Volver</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            @*<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccionesInmediata, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>*@

                                <div class="form-group relative">
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ModeloUno")" class="btn btn-default col-lg-offset-7 col-lg-2">Cancelar</a>
                                    <button id="btnGuardar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-3">Guardar</button>
                                </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="clienteModal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="pedidoModal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="usuarioModal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="contactoModal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>

    @section scripts
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
                $("#btnGuardar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            });

        </script>
    }
}

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ModeloUno CONF)
    {


        return View("Create");

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: puedes subir el codigo? asi se entendera mejor el problema

Comment: Si, si Desde luego. Gracias!

Comment: Tenes un solo input en el formulario? Que datos pretendes recibir?

Comment: Tengo varios input, pero al agregar al menos uno solo ya me tira el error.
Mi idea es recibir en el controller, un objeto con todos sus atributos cargados segun el formulario.

Comment: Tu modelo se llama igual que tu controlador?

Comment: Si, si, El controlador se llama igual que la carpeta que contiene las vistas, y dentro tiene la funcion que posee el nombre del post al que llama la vista.
Si yo no envio ningun input, llega perfecto al controlador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, me falto declarar le primary key de la tabla.
Despues me aparecia un error referente al modelo.
Y vi que en la clase estaba como DATETIME, y en la tabla también como DATETIME. Pero al momento de hacer el insert enviaba DATETIME2.